# An efficient way to grow a data frame using a by function

Tags: r

I need to do some analysis on vehicles that are identified by their `ID`. The results of this analysis will include some `numeric`, `factor`, and `logical` information. All the data used in the analysis is in one data frame, so that the function goes like this:

```
Results <- by(Data, Data$ID, Function)
```

Where `Function` is designed to give output like this:

```
Function <- function(DF) {
                          ## Do stuff...
                          return(c(23.2, as.factor("SuperFast"), TRUE))
                         }
```

What's been great about this approach so far is that in addition to being quite fast (taking ~1 min where a `for` loop took hours), it's easy to put in `data.frame` format by:

```
as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", Results))
```

But of course, `c` in `Function` **and** `"rbind"` in `do.call` coerce everything into the same object type. To resolve this, I've been making `Function` spit out a character vector (like `as.character(23.2, "SuperFast", TRUE)` and then changing object types manually at the end.

Is there (1) a way to return something that can be a `row` in a dataframe that has different object types or (2) a better method than using `by` and `c` (for rows)?

Just for kicks, here's something that can be used for Data:

```
Data <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2,3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return a data frame instead of a vector from your function:

```
Function <- function(DF) {
    ## Do stuff...
    return(data.frame(a = 23.2,b = as.factor("SuperFast"),c = TRUE))
}
```

As an aside, the only thing coercing everything to the same data type was `c`. `rbind` has a data frame method that will (mostly) preserve types, assuming all the data frames you pass to it line up.

Comment: Thanks - it feels silly to have missed that but I'm glad it was something simple. I think I tried to avoid a method like that before because I was `rbind`ing stuff with different `colnames`, but since this is all coming from the same function it should work perfectly.